# Counting specials

Tags: c++, arrays

//can anyone tell me what and where i'm doing wrong with counting spcials.

```
int countSpecials(int arr[], int sizeof_array, int K)
{
    
    int f = floor(sizeof_array/K), count = 0;
    int pr =0; // to find how many times prop == f
    int prop; // to campare with f
    // Your code here
    for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof_array; i++){
        prop = 0;
        for(int j = 0 ; j < sizeof_array; j++){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j])
                prop++;
        }
        if(prop == f)
            pr++;
    }
    
    if(prop == 1)
        count = 0;
    else if(prop >1)
        count = f;

    return count;
    
}
```

Comment: what is the code supposed to do, what does it do instead? Why do *you*  think that there is something wrong?

Comment: `std::map` seems better if you want to count frequencies.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if the best names for variables you can think of are "f", "pr", and "prop", and you need comments to explain to yourself what they are good for, you don't really know what they are good for.

Comment: Your function returns either 0 or `floor(sizeof_array/K)`, and the choice only depends on the final iteration of the loop.

Comment: @molbdnilo Given the `your code here` comment I have the horrible feeling that these variable names were not chosen by the poster.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of obvious problems with the shown code.

```
int f = floor(sizeof_array/K);
```

Both `sizeof_array` and `K` are integers. So this is integer division, and in C++ the result of an integer division is an integer and the remainder gets thrown away.. Converting an integer to a floating point value, in order to pass it to `floor()`, will always convert an integer number. `floor()` always gets a whole number, does absolutely nothing, and the result gets converted back to an integer. Absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever, gets accomplished by that. It's completely unnecessary to use `floor()` in the first place. `int f=sizeof_array/K;` will work equally well.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < sizeof_array; i++){
    prop = 0;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < sizeof_array; j++){
        if(arr[i] == arr[j])
            prop++;
    }
```

The intent of this logic appears to be to find duplicate values in the array. The reason for that is somewhat unclear, but this logic seems to be obviously flawed.

Consider an array with just one value: `arr[]={5};`. The above logic will find a duplicate when `i` is 0 and `j` is 0. Both the inner and the outer for-loop iterate over the ***entire*** array. The sole comparison gets made is with both `i` and `j` and 0, which discovers a duplicate value. After, don't you agree that with `i` and `j` being 0, `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` are equal to each other? We must have a duplicate!

Consider an array with just three values: `arr[]={5, 1, 5}`. The outer `for` loop will start with `i` is 0. When `j` is both `0` and `2`, the above logic will find a duplicate.

But when `i` reaches the value of `2`, and the inner loop begins, and `j` is `0` and `2` again that's going to be another duplicate. You now have four duplicates here. And, of course, `1` is a duplicate of itself. So, in this array of three values, by my count we've just found five duplicates.

The overall purpose for finding duplicates in the shown program appears to be somewhat unclear, but it's obvious that the core logic is flawed, and it needs to be fixed accordingly. This is where it seems to be "doing wrong with counting specials".